# Оптимизация и сжатие изображений FuelPHP

Tags: php

Какие есть бесплатные способы сжатия изображений при загрузке на сайт? Сайт построен на FuelPHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В FuelPHP есть файл (fuel/app/config/image.php) - возможно у вас по другому адресу он есть. image.php - содержит масив параметров для обработки изображения при загрузке, там нашол параметр quality который отвечает за оптимизацию изображдения (по умолчанию там стоит 100), поставил 70, все работает. После загрузки изображения оптимизированы

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать библиотеку php умеющую сжимать изображения, их большой выбор вы сможете найти на Github, по запросу image compressor php.

Так же вы можете использовать программу доступную для использования из консоли, одна из них ImageMagic, можете почитать про выполнение консольных команд с помощью php.